# Appended content using jQuery 'append' is not submitted?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery so this may be a real simple answer.  I have a ASP.NET project that I'm trying to dynamically add content to an ASP Label element by typing into a text box and clicking a button. Sounds simple right?  Well, I can get the content to added, but when the form is submitted the Label element is still empty?  Why is the new data not submitted?  What step am I missing?  Please help.  Here's some sample code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblContainer" Text="" runat="server" />
<input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" />
<input type="button" name="AddTag" value="Add" class="button" onclick="addTag();" />


function addTag() {
    if ($("#tag").val() != "") {
        $("#lblContainer").append('$("#tag").val()' + '<br />');
        $("#tag").val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the Format Code button instead of "cleverly" working around the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net doesn't work that way because it won't send the contents of a `<span>` tag in the HTTP Post when your form is submitted. You need to add that content to an `<input>` of some sort. Try something like this instead.

```
<span id="tagContainer" runat="server"></span>
<input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" />
<input type="button" name="AddTag" value="Add" class="button" onclick="addTag();" />

<!-- Use a hidden field to store the tags -->
<asp:HiddenField id="tagText" runat="server" />

function addTag() {
  var newTag = $.trim($("#tag").val());
   if (newTag != "") {
      $("#tag").val("");
      $("#tagContainer").append(" "+ newTag);

      // append the newTag to the hidden field
      var $tagText = $("#tagText");
      $tagText.val($tagText.val() + " " + newTag);
   }
}
```

Then in your asp.net code you can retrieve the value like so..

```
string myTagText = tagText.value;
```

Comment: So the snag with that answer is that I simplified my example. Actually, with each tag I add I'm also adding a button that can be clicked to remove the element from the list (onclick="($(this).parent().remove()))

So I guess the new question here would be, how would I keep this hiddenfield value up to date when the user can delete any tag they wish?!

Comment: I did. An ASP Label should be updating/submitting right?! I must be missing something silly.